# How do I listen to song samples on the iTunes website?

Tags: 10.04, itunes

How do I listen to song samples on the iTunes website in Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: what happens when you try to do it?

Comment: I hear nothing.

Comment: do you have gstreamer's ugly/bad etc plugins installed?

Comment: Yes. Those are all installed.

Comment: @NOYB Comments end up buried, when someone asks you for more detail just edit your question directly, thanks!

Comment: This question is abandoned - if you feel this is wrong, then please flag this for the moderators, and explain that this is not abandoned. :)

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox or Chrome I can confirm that clicking on the play icon does not do anything. However when you display the **page source** your are able to see direct links to previews in plain non-encrypted m4a format. Open these links in your browser and they will play if your audio plugin is capable to play m4a.

I suspect some broken Java implementation responsible. Maybe there is an addon anybody knows of?

Comment: java?___________

Comment: ___ or any other web control fancy stuff. I'm not a specialist for those things. However the preview files do play if you load them manually. It seems that it's "only" the play button that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to venture that the iTunes previews are encrypted with DRM.

Comment: Yes, that may be it. Well, there is always Amazon Music Store.

Comment: Negative. Previews are non-encrypted m4a.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhh.... well in that case my suggestion to trouble shoot this one is to see if they can play in VLC. To test that, try flashgot in firefox (to download the preview) and then open it in VLC. If no sound comes out, then there is a **REAL BIG PROBLEM.**